# How to enable remote microphone on remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, audio, remote-desktop, skype, microphone

I just directly connect my thin client (with embedded OS) to a remote machine (Windows 7) via RDP.
The problem is, once I try to test the audio via Skype, it seems that the audio/microphone of the remote machine was hidden or not detected, but the remote audio was detected too because
I could play music or videos.
Is there a way to enable the microphone of the remote machine and used as the microphone of my thin client?

Answer (score 48):

Before connecting to the remote computer, click on `Show Options` > Go to `Local Resources` tab > click <kbd>Settings</kbd> in the audio configuration. You can enable the recording from your local PC to the remote computer.

[image]

Comment: This is default in windows mstsc, should never be touched and the one thing everybody suggests on this problem everywhere on the internet. I'm surprised not one in here suggested to reinstall Windows. 
The thing is, if this was the actual real solution to the problem (no sound on remote), we wouldn't have so many with this problem. I have sound when I play Youtube videos on my remote, however Skype says not audio device is present. Some setting in MSTSC is not gonna change that

Comment: No, by default it is set to "Do not record", and apparently this did fix the issue to many people. Keep in mind the issue is the recording, not the playback.

Comment: I agree I came of a bit better knowing - however, the problem is getting the mike working on the remote computer in Skype, not the sound in general. The fact that the Mike does not work on remote is also confirmed in another comment, further down.

Comment: My example on sound was to make the point, that even though I have enabled, "Play on this computer", I don't see any sound device in Skype on the remote. 
I suspect the same problem applies to the mike problem.

Answer (score 2):

On desktop Windows clients, the mic setting is in the "new connection" dialog, under Local Resources / Remote audio [Settings...] / Remote audio recording: Record from this computer.

However, it sounds like you're trying to record audio on the remote computer, which is not an available option for the native clients. It's possible that other clients can support this feature, but it may also be a limitation of RDP, which would make it impossible.

Comment: can you elaborate for transferring audio in and out, am very sorry, I'm new with this.

Comment: Audio out = speakers, audio in = microphone. What RDP client do you have?

Comment: here it is the setup, hence the thin client has an embedded os(xp) i used the default remote desktop to remotely connect my remote machine windows 7. And also in my hp thin client I connect a usb headset to used as audio and microphone since this is testing setup for a call center. But sad to say once I got connected via the rdp it seems the microphone is hidden or not detected when i tested on skype [under on audio settings: Microphone=>None]

Comment: Are you trying to record audio from the thin client (possible), or from the remote machine (not possible)?

Comment: So it means, that we can't use the mic? okay, thank you for the information.

Comment: Maybe, I'm confused by your setup, since you have a USB mic plugged into the thin client, but you say you want to record it from the remote machine.

Comment: I'm very sorry for not being detailed of my info, what I want is, I want to enable my microphone so that I could make a conversation to other users in skype via internet, hence as of now only me can hear the voice of the receiver but they can't.

Comment: I have sound on my remote computer playing youtube video using MSTSC. Skype is installed on this very remote computer and Skype says no audio is present. Go figure.
Forget everything related to MSTSC when you look for solutions.