# How to enable local microphone to use on remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, audio, remote-desktop, microphone

I want to talk to the microphone of a local machine on Skype of a remote machine. 
Unfortunately, [this solution](https://superuser.com/q/741435/150988#1140147) did not work:

> Before connecting to the remote computer, click on "Show Options" >
> Go to "Local Resources" tab > click "Settings" in the audio configuration. 
> You can enable the recording from your local PC to the remote computer.

And no input device is known in the remote machine.

Local is Windows 7 and remote is Windows 10.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have installed correct microphone drivers on Win 10.

Enable below two policies on Win 10.

Computer Configration\Administrative Templates\Windows Componets\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection

- Allow audio and video playback redirection
- Allow audio recording redirection

Show Options" > Go to "Local Resources" tab > Click "more" under Local devices and resources >check all boxes
[image]